# When trying to retrieve JSONObject out of JSONArray is returning null?

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

Im trying to do the following:

```
UserFunctions uf = new UserFunctions();
    JSONArray json = uf.getAllFreebies();
    System.out.println(json + "blah1"); //Here im able to retrieve the whole JSONArray.

try{    
System.out.println("1");
    for (int i = 1; i <json.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println("2");
            jo = json.optJSONObject(i); //Im getting null value here
            System.out.println(jo + "blah2"); //Here im getting null
```

...}

Im printing out my JSONArray using following lines.

```
JSONArray json = uf.getAllFreebies();
System.out.println(json + "blah1");
```

Now on the following lines when i tried to retrieve the JSONObject from the JSONArray and tried to print it out,it prints out "null" instead of the JSONObject at the particular index.

```
jo = json.optJSONObject(i);
System.out.println(jo + "blah2");
```

Can anyone pls tell me what am i doing wrong?I mean how can i get a null for JSONOBject when my JSONArray is not null?

Thank You.

Following is my JSONArray logcat:

```
05-31 21:02:57.156: I/System.out(318): [["viking","Art","Potrait","Potrait","Good","im giving out potrait 7325697","176 Fiat Ave","Iselin","New Jersey","USA","08830","2012-05-27"],["n00b","Books","Novels","Novels","Good","Im giving out novels 7325697","b9 maa krupa","petlad","Gujarat","India","388450","2012-05-27"],["n00b","Computers","laptop","laptop giveaway","Good","Im giving out laptop if you are interested than pls call on 7325697","B9 Ma  Krupa","Petlad","Gujarat","India","388450","2012-05-27"],["mista","Cameras & Photos","Camera","Camera GiveAway","Very good","im giving out camera .its kodak .pls email me on mista@gmail.com","Mista Lee elm street","seoul","Korea","South Korea","ha8 9sd","2012-05-27"],["panda","Gaming Consoles","XBOX","XBOX 360","Very Good","Im giving out xbox 360.if you are interested please email me on panda@gmail.com","435 Carmen Rd,","Buffalo","New York","USA","14226","2012-05-27"],["viking","Cameras & Photos","Camera","Kodak Camera","Good","Kodak Camera giveaway.Pls call on 732397","","Iselin","New Jersey","USA","08830","2012-05-28"],["viking","Books","Novels","Novel GA","Good","Novel give away.call on 7325697.","","Iselin","New Jersey","USA","08830","2012-05-28"],["viking","Automotive","Car","Car GiveAway","Good","Im giving out car.if you are interested pls call 7323697.","176 Fiat Ave","Iselin","New Jersey","USA","08830","2012-05-29"],["viking","Collectibles","Medallions","Medallion GA","Very Good","Im giving out medallion.if inetrested pls call 732697","176 Fiat Ave,","Iselin","New Jersey","USA","08830","2012-05-29"],["viking","Clothing & Accessories","cloths","cloths giveaway","Good","im giving out cloths if you are interested pls call on 735697","176 Fiat Ave,","Iselin","New jersey","USA","08830","2012-05-29"],["viking","Books","Novel","Novel GA","Good","pls call 735697","435 carmen rd","buffalo","ny","usa","14226","2012-05-29"],["viking","Books","TextBook","CHemistry 101","GOod","pls call 735697","176 fiat ave","iselin","new jersey","usa","08830","2012-05-29"],["mista","Books","Notebook","Notbook","Good","im giving out notebbok if you are interested pls call 48374288423","elm street","seaoul","na","South Korea","jfjafjk","2012-05-29"]]blah1
```

logcat output when trying to print out JSONOBject at index i

```
05-31 21:02:57.156: I/System.out(318): nullblah2
```

Comment: `jo = json.getJSONObject(i);`

Comment: Any chance of posting the JSONArray output you logged?  It may be a bad object.  If `JSONArray` cannot coerce the value at that index into a `JSONObject` it will return null.  Also just try calling `json.opt(i)` to get a raw result that the array doesn't try to coerce.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya thanks for the response. jo.json.getJSONObject(i); is same as jo = json.optJSONObject(i); both returns JSONOBject from the index but the only difference is that optJSONOBject returns nulls if JSONOBject is not found at the  unlike getJSONOBject.Also i tried using getJSONOBject() is not working either

Comment: **Post the JSON itself.** It is most likely a simple mistake/mismatch. Note that `opt` is short for *optional* and thus `null` is a valid result. (My -1 and "too localized" was for not providing adequate information.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON `[[...], [...], [...]]` does not contain JSON-objects, but it does have some JSON-arrays.

Thus `optJSONObject` finds a JSON-array (where it expected a JSON-object) and returns `null` because it is of the incorrect type. (`opt` is short for *optional*.)

Use `optJSONArray` (note *Array* and not *Object*). Alternatively, use `getJSONArray`, which will throw a JSONException on failure.

Happy coding.

---

Note that JSON keeps a strict distinction between Objects, Arrays, and the various Values. The concept of an Array being a special (sub)kind of Object (in the JSON sense) exists in JavaScript but *does not* necessarily extend to other JSON implementations. For instance, the [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) class has *no* relationship with the JSONObject class.

Comment: One quick question.
As you can see im getting JSONArray JSONArray json = uf.getAllFreebies(); so now as you told me i have JSONArrays does that mean i have JSONArray of JSONArray's? Also should i now declare new JSONArray and do JSONArray js = json.getJSONArray(i);?

Comment: Yes, there are JSON-arrays in a JSON-array, so the conclusion is correct.